# how to upload file to Amazon s3 based on angularjs and ruby

Tags: ruby, angularjs, amazon-web-services

I am trying use the [ng-s3upload](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-s3upload/blob/master/README.md) to help me with the file upload to aws based on angualrjs.
In the read me file, the forth point is about the sever side code. I am quite confused about where should I put the ruby code in the ruby application, for example which folder, and should I do some change on the policy, signature and key.

Is there anyone use the ng-s3upload before? Thanks in advance if someone could help me on that!

Comment: I apologise as this comment isn't particularly useful. I found the amazon documentation very out dated and often led you down the wrong path. Good luck.

Comment: @RobWhite I am trying to use the ng-s3upload, but I am not sure how to use the ruby code. could you look into it and do me a favour?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've never dealt with ruby, wouldnt know where to start. I'm a Asp.Net developer